# Issue with Tensorflow tensor and eager execution

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow2.x

I would like to convert a Tensorflow tensor into a numpy array.
My code looks as follows:

```
t = tf.gather_nd(angle, [1,1]) # extract row 1, column 1 element of angle tensor

t = t.numpy() # convert tensor t to numpy array
```

which results in:

```
AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'numpy'
```

I've tried different things that are proposed [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/27519), like trying out different Tensorflow versions (2.0,2.2,2.7) and triggering eager execution with tf.compat.v1.enable_eager_execution() or tf.enable_eager_execution() but  the error message remains. I have used Python 3.7 on all Tensorflow versions.

Has anyone faced a similar issue? Im running out of ideas on this one.

Comment: Please update your post to include your Tensorflow version.

Answer (score 0):

What does the `angle` parameter consist of? You can try again by upgrading your existing `TensorFlow` in your system which will upgrade the `numpy` version also.

```
!pip install --upgrade tensorflow
```

It seems there is no problem with `tf.gather_nd()` api.

Suppose,

```
angle = np.array([['a', 'b'],['c', 'd']])

t = tf.gather_nd(angle, [1,1]) # extract row 1, column 1 element of angle tensor


print(t)
type(t)
```

Output:

```
tf.Tensor(b'd', shape=(), dtype=string)
tensorflow.python.framework.ops.EagerTensor
```

After converting this `tensor` to `numpy`:

```
t = t.numpy()
print(t)
type(t)
```

Output:

```
b'd'
bytes
```